# Jquery mouseover buttonset isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mouseover

I'm having problems with the mouseover event not firing in the next code (the click event fires ok):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
      .invisible {
        display: none;
      }
    //-->
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
      $('.menu').menu();
      $('#radio1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#menu1').removeClass('invisible');
      });
      $('#radio1').click(function(){
        $('#menu1').removeClass('invisible');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <ul id="menu1" class="menu invisible">
      <li><a href="#">Uno</a></li>
      <li><a>Dos</a></li>
      <li><a>Tres</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The mouseover event is ignored at all (see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/YyCde/) and the click event works as expected.
Is this the expected behavior or there is a bug or I'm missing something? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, if you inspect the DOM in the browser inspector or FireBug, the radio button is not spanning across. Instead the `label` acts as the button. Hence the `mouseover` isn't fired on the `radio`. Try this:

```
$('#radio1').next('label').on('mouseover', function(e){
    $('#menu1').removeClass('invisible');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)

```
$('label[for="radio1"]').on('mouseover', function(e){
    $('#menu1').removeClass('invisible');
});
```

It works. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/YyCde/2/).

Comment: I'd go with `label[for=radio1]` over the `.next` stuff.

Comment: Yep! I didn't know that filter existed! ;)